# Script Grease Pencil Interpolation?

Tags: scripting, grease-pencil, interpolation, library-overrides

Trying to interpolate using `bpy.ops.gpencil.interpolate()` and `bpy.ops.gpencil.interpolate_sequence()` which need a context override so I tried this code:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for window in context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            with context.temp_override(window=window, area=area):
                bpy.ops.gpencil.interpolate_sequence() 
            break
```

Results in a crash. Maybe it's not possible to do interpolation this way?

Comment: Hello and welcome. see [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add/270716#270716) for more information on how to use context properly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add/270716#270716

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get the override to work, so a workaround is to run the code as an addon, then I don't need to override the context.